# Java "store.steampowered.com/login/"

Tags: jsoup, html, java, синтаксический-анализ

В общем, нужен мне небольшой парсер для сайта, указанного в заголовке. Но проблема в том, что я не могу пройти процедуру идентификации.

Пробовал с помощью jsoup по [примеру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719806/jsoup-cant-login-to-establish-cookies), стандартной библиотеки с передачей запроса в форме `login=qwerty&password=passqwerty` через `DataOutputStream`, [как тут](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/). Но это не помогло. Взялся посмотреть HTMLunit, но он не работает "из коробки", т.е. не поддерживает javascript почему-то, и вообще все плохо с ним.

Как можно все же залогиниться, используя java, подскажете?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, можно, но ненужно, явно интерфейс для человека предназначен.

Что у steem'а API https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API недостаточно?

Просто если реально нужно так логиниться, то придётся самостоятельно js разобрать и запрос составить.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, а можно чуть поподробнее как таки JS разбирать в таких случаях? Мне похожую задачу решить надо, но в какую сторону гуглить, даже не знаю(

Comment: Ну вы посмотрите что в запросе при логине передаётся, а потом смотрите как формируется в javascript.